# Keypress simulation with Batch-JScript duo not working as expected

Tags: batch-file, automation, simulation, keypress, jscript

After doing some googling I got many answers(from stackoverflow and other sites) saying keypress automation & simulation is possible with Batch-JScript duo file, so I put together my fndings and made a script like below, but it doesn't work as expected at all.

Take a look at the below script:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
start SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe
%SendKeys% "{n}"
goto :EOF
@end
::JScript section
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

As it is apparent from the code, I a trying open the **Environment Variables** section which is already elevated to **Administrator** rights, so that user can edit both `User` and `System` environment variables. But this script only opens the Window **before** Environment Variables in elevated privilege.

As you can see, I have already put the code to simulate & automate keypress of `n` letter after opening the SystemPropertiesAdvanced Window and thus bypassing that manual step, but this part doesn't work.

Maybe I have made some mistake, but I cannot find what would that be, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: The window probably hasn't been created by the time you send `n`.  Using sendkeys is good practise to `AppActivate` first as well as `wscript.sleep`.

Comment: But I can't figure out, how to do AppActivate in my code, as my code does sendkeys in middle of batch code, also when it encounters `goto :EOF` it just exits the console and stops the program execution, can you please explain with similar example to my code in an answer or link ?

Comment: `WshShell.AppActivate(WScript.Arguments(1));`

Comment: To send a `n` character just use `"n"`; perhaps the `"{n}"` form not works... See the [Sendkeys documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx)